# Creating stub classes for a rmi project

Tags: java, rmi

I have an assignment with java rmi, and now I want to create the stub classes for this project, but I dont know how.

I want to learn how to create stub for rmi projects. Can you help please. I would rather a detailed answer.

Comment: I want you to tag this question properly :)

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read through the [RMI tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/index.html), this [second tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/rmi/RMI.html), and the [docs for `rmic`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/rmic.html). If those don't help you, you can then ask a more specific question explaining which bit wasn't covered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create stub classes at all. See the preamble to the Javadoc for UnicastRemoteObject.

Answer (score 0):

Since J2SE 5, stub classes no longer need to be pre-generated. There's still lots of old tutorials out there, so that might be confusing at first.

Here's a nice, more recent [Hello World tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html) for RMI that'll get you going.